Godot/GDScript accessing NodePaths in Array
I am making a game in Godot where each NPC has a list of enemies which can be changed at any time (will have a "friends" one too eventually), and thought I should make an array so I can drag characters in where needed. The only way I can seemingly do that is with a NodePath, but when I use get_node(enemies[0]) in my state machine, it is returning a null instance. Where am I going wrong?

You should really try to explain your current state better, because there could be a ton of options that suit the problem better than using NodePaths. My assumption from the info you given us is, that you save a path from inside a NPC and try to get it from another node (statemachine). This will lead to an inconsistent root and he will not find it. Also if the enemy node changes it's parent for some reason, it wont work either.
